# Connect wii remote with python3

Tags: python-3.x, bluetooth, controller, pygame

I want to make a program that utilises a Nintendo wii remote for its controls. It connects via bluetooth to my computer. How can I make python recognize this controller and use it in a program?
It would be interesting to hear both a python-only solution and a pygame one.

Comment: What have you tried? If you haven't attempted anything at all then I would recommend starting with [pybluez](https://github.com/karulis/pybluez).

Comment: Is there any way without external modules?

Comment: Yes there is a way, but I believe it is well outside of the scope of a single stackoverflow question. [pybluetooth](https://github.com/pebble/pybluetooth) claims to have a pure python implementation of bluetooth so you could look at the source if that's really something you're interested in writing. Otherwise stick with an external library. pybluez is probably the best option here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you are using windows, I first used [Julian Loehr's wiimote gamepad](https://www.julianloehr.de/educational-work/hid-wiimote/) driver to have it recognized as a gamepad. Then I used pygame's joystick library to detect it, and used the axes and button checks.

This code should help you get started:

```
import pygame
from time import sleep

pygame.init()

try:
    j=pygame.joystick.Joystick(0)
except pygame.error: # This bit doesn't seem to work properly.
    print("Joystick not connected.")

j.init()

while 1:
    pygame.event.pump()

    if round(j.get_axis(0))== -1: #Up key when holding it vertically
        #do something
    elif round(j.get_axis(0))== 1: #Down key
        #something else
    elif round(j.get_axis(1))== -1: #Right
        #something
    elif round(j.get_axis(1))== 1: #Left
        #something

    if j.get_button(0): # Button 1
        #something
    elif j.get_button(1): #2
        #something
    elif j.get_button(2): #A
        #something
    elif j.get_button(3): #B
        #something
    elif j.get_button(4): #Plus
        #something
    elif j.get_button(5): #Minus
        #something
    elif j.get_button(6): #Home
        #something
    else:
        pass
```

If you are using linux, you can take a look at cwiid if you are using python2. If you use python 3, you can use bluetoothctl from the terminal to connect, then use evdev to read key and accelerometer events.